# Excel 2007 Change colour of bars in a single series, based on another field

Tags: excel, colors, bar-chart, series

I have a pivot table with data like this:

```
Chain     Store               Units
Bob's     BB Los Angeles        10
Bob's     BB San Diego          12
Tom's     TM Los Angeles        12
Tom's     TM San Francisco      18
Kate's    K Monterey            11
```

Currently I have a bar chart just showing all stores and units in descending order, so TM San Francisco is first, then TM Los Angeles and BB San Diego, then K Monterey etc. This is how I want to see the data.

But I also want to colour code the chains, so Bob's stores have a red bar, Tom's have blue, and Kate's are green.

Is it possible to do this? I've tried various ways of setting out the pivot table but it ends up looking a mess and I can't find a way of basing the each bar's colour on the 'chain' field.

=

Am testing the macro solution, but if anyone has a non-macro solution then do please still answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a macro/VBA-based solution, this is pretty easy to manipulate the chart's data point formatting.  Assuming that the series XValues = Chain, you could do this:

```
Sub SetColors()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim xVals As Variant
Dim p As Long

Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart '<-- Modify as needed'
Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection(1) '<-- Modify as needed'

xVals = srs.XValues  '<-- modify as needed, if your Chain is not part of series data you will need to build this array another way'

For p = 1 To UBound(xVals)
    Select Case xVals(p)
        Case "Bob's"
            srs.Points(p).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case "Tom's"
            srs.Points(p).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case "Kate's"
            srs.Points(p).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

If the Chain is NOT part of the series data, you'd have to change the way that `xVals` is set, but the general principle should still apply: Iterate over the points in the series, check against a reference list, and apply a specific color based on the reference item.

Comment: That's great, that works thanks. The loop needs to stop at UBound(xVals)-1 else the next (p + 1) reference causes an error, and I changed the Case statements to IFs so I could use wildcards, but it does what I wanted to do. Unfortunately, the resultant chart looks terrible, but that's my problem..... :)

Comment: @Wilskt I modified to prevent the error. `xVals` is a 1-indexed array, not 0-index as had originally written, so `For p = 1 to ...` and removed the `+1` inside the loop.  Otherwise, glad it's working for you with some minor tweaks!