# Automatically Set Chart Series Colors to Match Source Cell Colors by Category not Series

Tags: excel, vba, colors, charts

I have a VBA code to automatically change the color in a chart, which I found from this site: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/automatically-set-chart-series-colors-to-match-source-cell-colors/

The code is posted below. My problem is that I need this code to apply to the chart's horizontal categories instead of the series because I am using a horizontal bar chart and the data has to be arranged in this way. How can I change the VBA to apply the automatic color change to the categories?

```
Sub CellColorsToChart()
Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim FormulaSplit As Variant
Dim SourceRange As Range
Dim SourceRangeColor As Long

'Loop through all charts in the active sheet
For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    'Loop through all series in the target chart
   For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

        'Get Source Data Range for the target series
       FormulaSplit = Split(MySeries.Formula, ",")

        'Capture the first cell in the source range then trap the color
       Set SourceRange = Range(FormulaSplit(2)).Item(1)
        SourceRangeColor = SourceRange.Interior.Color

        On Error Resume Next
        'Coloring for Excel 2003
       MySeries.Interior.Color = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Border.Color = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.MarkerForegroundColorIndex = SourceRangeColor

        'Coloring for Excel 2007 and 2010
       MySeries.MarkerBackgroundColor = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.MarkerForegroundColor = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Format.Line.BackColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor
        MySeries.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = SourceRangeColor

    Next MySeries
Next oChart

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to [iterate the points in (each) series, and apply color to each individual point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014342/excel-2007-change-colour-of-bars-in-a-single-series-based-on-another-field/16014797#16014797)

Answer (score 0):

The following code does something along the lines you are asking. It iterates through the points and colours them to the background colour of the cell and iterates through multiple series if they exist.

```
Sub CellColorsToChart()
Dim oChart As ChartObject
Dim MySeries As Series
Dim FormulaSplit As Variant
Dim SourceRangeColor As Long
Dim seriesArray() As Variant
Dim pointIterator As Integer

For Each oChart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    For Each MySeries In oChart.Chart.SeriesCollection

        seriesArray = MySeries.Values
        For pointIterator = 1 To UBound(seriesArray)
            FormulaSplit = Split(MySeries.Formula, ",")
            SourceRangeColor = Range(FormulaSplit(2)).Item(pointIterator).Interior.Color
            MySeries.Points(pointIterator).Interior.Color = SourceRangeColor
        Next pointIterator
    Next MySeries
Next oChart

End Sub
```