# Set series of chart by cells interior color

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am working in a  code with VBA 
to Set series of chart by cells interior color.  I mean if you change the interior color of cell in data sheet, in the chart appear new serie with the new color. It is possible? I can't do it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924456/automatically-set-chart-series-colors-to-match-source-cell-colors-by-category-no?rq=1  Please also review the questions listed under "Related" on this page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event in Excel to detect an interior color change. I recommend the following two ways:

1. If you are changing the interior color manually, then put the function recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924456/automatically-set-chart-series-colors-to-match-source-cell-colors-by-category-no?rq=1) (also referenced by @Tim Williams) in your workbook's "selection changed" event. By this way, once changed the interior color, you have to click another cell other than the currently selected cell to trigger the event and change the series color.
2. If you are changing the interior color somewhere in your code, then only call the function mentioned above after changing interior color.